# how can i pass a parameter from ASP.NET to SSRS Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportingservices-2005

I need to pass a value as a parameter from ASP.Net application to SSRS Report.How can i do this?Can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the following line and try it...

```
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("http://MyPC/reportserver");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/ReportFolder/Reportname";

        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] Param = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[3];
        Param(2) = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("SDATE", "02/02/2002");
        Param(1) = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("EDATE", "09/06/2000");
        Param(0) = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("TASK", 0);

        View.ReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        View.ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(Param);
        View.ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: My report is stuck in "Loading" screen and not displaying the data. Any idea?

Comment: A minor typo in Amit Patel's code: Param[2] etc. should be square brackets around the index for C#.  I'm sure most can figure that out but it threw me for a bit (I use both vb.net and C#.net so it didn't initially look odd to me).

Comment: This is good on the code side, but can someone provide an SSRS screenshot, or walk through using the "Report Data" menu and "Parameters" option?

Comment: in my report its drop down value so how can i set the drop down value using ASp.net

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the parameter values in the URL used to get the report.

Also you should disable the "Promt user (for parameters)" in `/reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` for your report.

Example of setting a parameter named `ParameterName`:
`/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?...&ParameterName=ParameterValue`

[Viewing Reports with a Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237802.aspx)

Comment: An example is right there in the post - I have just omitted the parts specific to my environment.

Comment: If you have a param named `ParameterName` in your rdl, it should be available to the report rendering engine as the `=Parameters!ParameterName.Value` expression with the value `ParameterValue` passed via the url in the example.
It depends whether your are using the reportManager by url or the ReportViewer control.
Also if you are not rendering SSRS (just confused the terms) and using a local reporting, use what **pranay_stacker** wrote.

Comment: where should i use the following syntax?
ParameterName: /Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?...&ParameterName=ParameterValue

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have assumed you are using the HTML Viewer of SSRS (dunno why).
Check the article on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237802.aspx (Viewing Reports with a Browser). There are other ways to do that of course.